# What have I done wrong? Static Errors [Java]

Tags: java, static

It refrences a error that I cannot use static when I used my function generatecode() I wanted to see if I did my split correctly. I am new and still need a bit of help. I've seen something on creating a new class via in this case: TestFile variable = new TestFile(); I had no idea what this means. Thanks!

```
    public class TestFile {

String[] preps = {
    "about", "above", "across", "after", "against",
    "along", "among", "around", "at", "before",
    "behind", "below", "beneath", "beside", "between",
    "by", "concerning", "down", "during", "except",
    "for", "from", "in", "inside", "into",
    "like", "near", "of", "onto", "out",
    "over", "through", "to", "toward", "under",
    "up", "upon", "with", "within", "without"
};

String[] errorpreps = {
    "will", "would", "shall", "should", "can",
    "could", "may", "might", "must", 
};

String[] question = {
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    generatecode("hi");

};

public generatecode(String code){

    String prep = "";

    for (int i=0; i<preps.length; i++){

        prep = prep + preps[i];

    }

    System.out.println(prep);

    return prep;

}

public String printcode(String code){


    return "";

}

    }
```

Comment: You should copy/paste *the exact* error message.

Comment: But your problem is the usual -- `generatecode` is an "instance" method and you're calling it from the static method `main` without creating and using an instance for the call.

Comment: How did this get an upvote?

Comment: @DonRoby - Because it was a better question than some of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `static` `main` method, you don't have any instances of your `TestFile` class yet.  To reference anything that is non-`static`, you need an instance of the class.  That is exactly what the line `TestFile variable = new TestFile();` does -- it creates a new instance of `TestFile`.

Then you can call your method on your instance:

```
variable.generatecode("hi");
```

As @ChrisCooney has already pointed out, you don't have a return type for that method.  All methods need a return type.  In this case, you need to declare that your method returns a `String`, because that's what the method does return.

Comment: Yep, and in addition add the String return type to the generatecode declaration.

Comment: Ooh I forgot to add String to that one function. Yeah I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has the wrong access modifier:

```
public generatecode(String code){
```

Should be

```
public static String generatecode(String code){
```

**Just to note**

You didn't have a return type for the method either, so this really shouldn't compile.

**Why is it like this?**

Well, static methods like `main(String[] args)` are capable of being ran, when there is no object instance. So you can call:

```
ClassName.method();
```

When you attempt to call an instance method from a static method, this means that you're trying to use code functionality that requires an object instance to exist. So just to recap:

```
ClassName c = new ClassName();
c.instanceMethod(); // This is an instance method.

ClassName.staticMethod(); // This is a static method.
```

Answer (score 0):

`generate` is an instance method, and you're trying to invoke it from `main`, which is a static method. To workaround it, you could do.-

`(new TestFile()).generatecode("hi");`

Comment: I was able to resolve taking a look at your method. This opened my eyes to that I needed to create the class as a object. Then I needed to call the variable. Unlike all the other methods didn't tell me where to load the new object.

Comment: Which I found out belongs inside the main function.